# Can I fixed first div of rows and scroll other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to fixed first div of rows, and need to scroll other divs horizontally.

Here is my current div set.

I have no idea whether it is possible or not.

```css
.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 450px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: left;
  overflow: auto;
  white-space: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.headings {
  display: block;
}
.headings .heading {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 167px;
  height: 42px;
  background: #66ccff;
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-bottom: 4px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 42px;
}
```

```html
<div class="content" id="container">
  <div class="headings">
    <div class="heading">12.00pm</div>
    <div class="heading">12:30pm</div>
    <div class="heading">12:00pm</div>
    <div class="heading">11:30am</div>
    <div class="heading">11:00am</div>
    <div class="heading">10:30am</div>
    <div class="heading">10:00am</div>
    <div class="heading">09:30am</div>
  </div>
  <!-- headings -->
  <div class="headings">
    <div class="heading">How is it</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 01</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 02</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 03</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 04</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 05</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 06</div>
  </div>
  <!-- headings -->
  <div class="headings">
    <div class="heading">How is it</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 01</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 02</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 03</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 04</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 05</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 06</div>
  </div>
  <!-- headings -->
  <div class="headings">
    <div class="heading">How is it</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 01</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 02</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 03</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 04</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 05</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 06</div>
  </div>
  <!-- headings -->
  <div class="headings">
    <div class="heading">How is it</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 01</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 02</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 03</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 04</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 05</div>
    <div class="heading">Next title 06</div>
  </div>
  <!-- end of content -->
</div>
<!-- end of content -->
```

What I want here is make every first div of rows fixed and others need to scroll horizontally. Refer my code snippet posted here.

Let me know whether it is possible or not.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: may i know the way..

Comment: @user2584538 what have you done so far?

Comment: @Jaromanda X yes of course, I need to know how can I accomplish this.

Comment: @alirezasafian That is what I posted.

Comment: @user2584538 First wrap those element by a `div` which should have scroll and the give overflow:scroll to that `div`.

Comment: @JaromandaX no actually I tried to do so by making parent parent div relatively and tried to make first div fixed position and placed, but it won't work. This grid I am generating from a JSON. These are dynamically generated data.

Comment: Did you tryied searching on stackoverflow for _table with fixed header_ ? or do you need not to use `<table>` tag ?

Comment: @Zeratops Yes I found as table. But Here I need to use DIVs instead of a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this kind.

```
       .content {

            height: 255px;
            padding: 10px;
            text-align: left;
            overflow: auto;
            white-space: nowrap;
            -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
            -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
            box-sizing: border-box;
        }
        .headings {
            display: block;
        }
        .headings .heading {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 150px;
            height: 42px;
            background: #66ccff;
            color: #fff;
            font-weight: 600;
            margin-bottom: 4px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 42px;
        }
       .time{position:fixed;z-index:9999}
       .text{margin-left:200px;}
```

```html
       <div class="content" id="container">
            <div class="headings ">
                <div class="heading time">12.00pm</div>
                <div class="text">
                <div class="heading">12:30pm</div>
                <div class="heading">12:00pm</div>
                <div class="heading">11:30am</div>
                <div class="heading">11:00am</div>
                <div class="heading">10:30am</div>
                <div class="heading">10:00am</div>
                <div class="heading">09:30am</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- headings -->

            <div class="headings">
                <div class="heading time">How is it</div>
                                <div class="text">
                <div class="heading">Next title</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 01</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 02</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 03</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 04</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 05</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 06</div>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- headings -->
            <div class="headings">
                <div class="heading time">How is it</div>
                                <div class="text">
                <div class="heading">Next title</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 01</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 02</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 03</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 04</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 05</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 06</div>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- headings -->
            <div class="headings">
                <div class="heading time">How is it</div>
                                <div class="text">
                <div class="heading">Next title</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 01</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 02</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 03</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 04</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 05</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 06</div>
                                    </div>
            </div>
            <!-- headings -->
            <div class="headings">
                <div class="heading time">How is it</div>
                <div class="text">
                <div class="heading">Next title</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 01</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 02</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 03</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 04</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 05</div>
                <div class="heading">Next title 06</div>
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <!-- end of content -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of content -->
```

Comment: you have fixed first row. I think you have misunderstand the question.

Comment: But what I need here is, scroll that first div that is fixed when horizontal scroll when scroll vertically